# Listening to "Triggers" and reacting to them in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

There are apps on Android such as [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and [Trigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher) that allows the user to set up some "Triggers" and the "Responses" that should execute when each trigger triggers.

The triggers could be, for instance: Connecting to a certain Wi-Fi, Arriving a certain location (Geo-Fencing), Plugging the earphone, tapping an NFC Tag and so forth.

I wonder if there's any way to to something like this on the Windows Phone platform. I have no background in developing for WPhones (even though i have a huge C# background), so i'm not sure whether the platform itself allows this sort of "background monitoring of sensors or, if there are such sensors (such as "headphone plug").

After a quick research, seems that [access to some APIs are not allowed from Background Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), i wonder if there's anything related to security here, or just an inability of the platform.

Is there any way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows Phone 8 you can perform background processing, with [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

You can use `Sceduled Taks`to register a class containing a method that is called periodically, even when your app is not running. They are multipurpose and offer the greatest utility for extending your app to perform background activities.

You can surely display a message to the user, or fire an alarm or something, a message would be more suited, for location aware apps. Those registered as geographic location providers are able to continue running despite there being another app running in the foreground.

For the rest of your triggers, I'm not sure. You'll have to check the [Sensors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: The link i've pasted on the question says that ALL Sensor API can't be accessed within a Background Agent. Does it mean that i can't read any of the sensors from a background thread?

Comment: Yes thats what it means. The only one that can be achieved from the listed actions in your question, is the arriving at certain location detection.

Comment: That sucks...I thought that microsoft wouldn't make the platform so closed when it comes to fun features. I hope that changes in the future

Comment: This is by design, in order to keep battery consumption low. I have to admit this is irritating, I had great app idea the other day engaging background activity, only to realize that this limitation makes the implementation impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't hook any triggers or events. The only thing you can, as Pantelis said, is to create very limited PeriodicTask that may or may not be run every roughly 30 minutes and be constrained to max 25s of running time. This is deliberate platform limitation, AFAIK done mostly because of battery usage and security reasons.

If something can't be achieved by PeriodicTask, give it up. This is the most versatile background process, others are even more limited. This is by design to prevent daemons from taking over the phone.